# Select results of stored procedure multiple times into a single result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that selects two random "Nomination" types from a table. A pair of Nominations constitutes what I call a "Battle". The nominations in each Battle belong to the same "Category".

```
create procedure sprocGetRandomBattle
as
select * from Nomination where NominationId in 
    (select top 2 NominationId from Nomination where IsActive = 1 and CategoryId in 
        (select CategoryId from Category where CategoryId in 
            (select top 1 CategoryId from Category where Active = 1 and CategoryId in 
                (select CategoryId from Nomination group by CategoryId having count(*) > 1)
            order by newid()) and OwnerId in 
        (select UserId from [User] where IsPrivate = 0))
    order by newid())
go
```

This sproc does a few things:

1. Get a random active category ID
2. Get 2 random Nomination IDs that: a) belong to the category we just randomly selected, b) are active nominations, and c) are owned by a user who is not marked as private.
3. Select Nominations for the 2 Nomination IDs we just randomly selected.

I'm doing this as a sproc instead of using LINQ because I would need to pull back increasingly larger result sets (over time as the data grows) in order to do a random selection in app code. So, I've moved that query into this sproc. I want to run this procedure N times (in SQL) and return its results in a single large set, so that I can avoid making multiple calls from app code to the SQl server. Right now, I just call the sproc in a loop in app code as many times as I need to (N).

How do I execute this sproc N multiple times in SQL and return it as one large result set? Or maybe I just need to modify the sproc somehow to take a parameter and return 2 x N results? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
create procedure sprocGetRandomBattle
@n int -- number of loops
as
declare @num int = 1;
declare @result table
    (
     -- input your column list
    )
while @num <=@n
begin   
insert into @result 
select * -- replace '*' with column list
from Nomination where NominationId in 
    (select top 2 NominationId from Nomination where IsActive = 1 and CategoryId in 
        (select CategoryId from Category where CategoryId in 
            (select top 1 CategoryId from Category where Active = 1 and CategoryId in 
                (select CategoryId from Nomination group by CategoryId having count(*) > 1)
            order by newid()) and OwnerId in 
        (select UserId from [User] where IsPrivate = 0))
    order by newid())
set @num = @num+1
end
select * from @result
go
```

I have declared an input parameter, to which you will need to pass the value of 'n'. The procedure will then run 'n' number of times in a loop and will populate the results into a table variable. On completion of the required loops, it is just a matter of selecting all results from the table variable.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm that this is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Works as expected.